# Keep getting error when using provider and signer that has been stored

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, ethers.js

I packaged a code snippet to get provider and signer. My tool is ethersjs,vue3,typescript
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxktB.png)

when i use:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfStc.png)

I will get problem in console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QfOP.png)

Whats wrong with my code ?

i want to use it as a hook, but this bug has been bothering me.